# Delete all objects except Checkboxes in VBA

Tags: vba, object, excel, checkbox

I have a sheet that contains some Form Control buttons, Form Control Checkboxes and the odd Shape. I currently have a macro that removes all objects from the sheet. (ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete)
What i woud like to do is have it remove all object EXCEPT the Checkboxes.
is this possible? and if so how would i go about it?

Comment: Do you have code that you have tried?  If you do, please post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in the sheet module

```
Sub test()

For Each DrawingObject In ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
    If TypeName(DrawingObject) <> "CheckBox" Then DrawingObject.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Delete only specific shapes

'What if you only want to delete control toolbox controls, Pictures or forms controls.
'You can loop through the collection and check the Type of the control.

'12 = ActiveX control (control toolbox) or a linked or embedded OLE object.
'13 = Picture
'8 = Forms controls

'For Type 8 we use another macro to avoid the problem of losing AutoFilter and Data Validation dropdowns on your worksheet.See the example in this section "Delete only Forms controls"

Sub Shapes2()
'Loop through the Shapes collection and use the Type number of the control
    Dim myshape As Shape
    For Each myshape In ActiveSheet.Shapes

    ' ActiveX control (control toolbox) or a linked or embedded OLE object

    If myshape.Type = 12 Then myshape.Delete

    ' You can also use  myshape.Visible = False

    Next myshape
'End Sub If you want to know all the Type numbers of all controls on your worksheet you can run this macro to add a new worksheet with the names and Type numbers of all objects on your worksheet.You can find the number then that you must use in the code to delete the objects you want.

Sub ListAllObjectsActiveSheet()

    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim myshape As Shape
    Dim I As Long

    Set MySheet = ActiveSheet
    Set NewSheet = Worksheets.Add

    With NewSheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Name"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Visible(-1) or Not Visible(0)"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Shape type"
        I = 2

        For Each myshape In MySheet.Shapes
            .Cells(I, 1).Value = myshape.Name
            .Cells(I, 2).Value = myshape.Visible
            .Cells(I, 3).Value = myshape.Type
            I = I + 1
        Next myshape

        .Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Range("A1:C" & Rows.Count).Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), _
                    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```